# can't display the console on glassfish 4 with java 8 144 and use eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

[image]How do I display the console on glassfish 4 using jdk 8 in eclipse?

Comment: no error notification is displayed, only does not display the console on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Right click on workspace provided by Eclipse > Select "Run As" > Java Application.